# Meaning of CV fields

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

There are three fields meanings of which are not clear for me in the "Completed Projects" part of the CV for IT-company. They are: Project Team (describe), Job Position, Project Roles.

Can anybody explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companies are interested where have you worked, on what position and what did you do. That's how the forms are formatted.

The project team block asks about the team that was involved in the project. You are to describe about the team and the people involved in.

Job position block asks for your job's position, your designation for that particular project (where you merely a programmer or handled the team as a TL).

Project Role block asks for your role in that project. You may have done some market research, coding, parsing, testing and so on for that project.

Put it in simple words, it's CV!

BTW, all the best!